# Rotation and Direction of ArcSegment

Tags: wpf, silverlight, geometric-arc, pathgeometry

Is there a way to get an ArcSegment to draw in a particular direction? As far as I can tell, it is always drawing top to bottom to top. For example, I have an ArcSegment which *starts* at 180 degrees (270 degrees is north) and draws an almost ellipse to 180 degrees. Right now, the drawing goes clockwise from....well, sorry, let me show you.

[image: things]

The left-hand one is the values I receive from a conversion set of values, but I need it to act like the right-hand one.

```
<Canvas Background="#FDB" Width="720" Height="540">
  <Path Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" Stroke="#385D8A" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="#4F81BD">
    <!-- this is the LEFT shape that I need drawn like the other one -->
    <Path.Data>
      <GeometryGroup>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,51" IsClosed="True">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="51,51" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="25.5,0">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="25.5,102" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="25.5,51" IsClosed="True" >
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <ArcSegment Size="25.5,25.5" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="25.49,51" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
          </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
      </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="100" Stroke="#385D8A" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="#4F81BD">
    <!-- this is the RIGHT shape, the way it should behave, but notice the different StartPoint and Point -->
    <Path.Data>
      <GeometryGroup>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,51" IsClosed="True">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="51,51" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="25.5,0">
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <LineSegment Point="25.5,102" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="51,25.5" IsClosed="True" >
              <PathFigure.Segments>
                <ArcSegment Size="25.5,25.5" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="50.99,25.5" />
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
          </PathGeometry.Figures>
        </PathGeometry>
      </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
</Canvas>
```

I've tried toying around with `RotationAngle`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect as it works only with the X-axis, not Y-axis.

The first Path's values come from a conversion routine, so it's not that I can easily modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out - just make the Y-axis shorter instead of the X-axis. So:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="51,25.5" IsClosed="True" >
    <PathFigure.Segments>
        <ArcSegment Point="50.99,25.5" Size="25.5,25.5" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise"  />
    </PathFigure.Segments>
</PathFigure>
```

should be:

```
<PathFigure StartPoint="51,25.5" IsClosed="True" >
    <PathFigure.Segments>
        <ArcSegment Point="51,24.99" Size="25.5,25.5" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise"  />
    </PathFigure.Segments>
</PathFigure>
```

As simple as that.